# Which button is "Reset transform" Button in Meta quest 3 controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

everyone.
I am developing Simple VR game, but I want to reset the position of XR rig object.
I saw this document and I am interested in Reset transform button.
Which button is the "Reset transform" Button in Meta quest 3 controller?

or is there any solution to reset the position of XR rig, please?

I am looking forwards to hearing from you and it is ok if you DM me., please.

I tried to reset the position of XR rig - transform. position = new vector (initial position)
But the position of XR rig is not reseted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no "Reset Button" but you can teleport XR rig when specified button pressed.

Comment: Thank you.
Could you please in more detail?
Could you guide me ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).